# Is it possible to render partials from a Ruby on Rails application to another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rendering, partial-views

I have two RoR3 applications (*APP1* and *APP2*)

- www.subdomain1.example.com
- www.subdomain2.example.com

and I want to show on *APP1* some views from *APP2*.

I tried to do that using a 'Net::HTTP' request (code in *APP1*)

```
Net::HTTP.get( URI.parse("http://www.subdomain2.example.com/users/new") )
```

but the response is not evaluated as HTTP code. Among other things I do not know if there are other techniques to do what I want in more easy way.

So, is it possible to render partials from *APP1* to *APP2* using the common and easy approach of rendering partials in the same RoR application?

Example:

```
render :partial => "/users/new"
```

If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, try this:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  require 'open-uri'

  def render_url(url)
    open url do |f|
      f.read.html_safe   # remove the 'html_safe' if you're on Rails 2.x
    end
  end
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= render_url 'http://ilikestuffblog.com/' %>
```

It will work.  Just one problem, though: if the site contains relative links to images, other pages, or anything else, those links will not be shown correctly.  Try this to see a bunch of blank images:

```
<%= render_url 'http://www.ducklet.com/' %>
```

Also, BE WARNED that if you don't own the URL you're including, you will be subject to cross-site scripting weirdness.

Answer (score 1):

If the two applications share a filesystem or have access to a shared filesystem, then you can reference a partial directly by file path.  From the Rails guide on rendering:

> 2.2.4 Rendering an Arbitrary File
>
> The render method can also use a view
> that’s entirely outside of your
> application (perhaps you’re sharing
> views between two Rails applications):
>
> render
> "/u/apps/warehouse_app/current/app/views/products/show"
>
> Rails determines that this is a file
> render because of the leading slash
> character. To be explicit, you can use
> the :file option (which was required
> on Rails 2.2 and earlier):
>
> render :file =>
> "/u/apps/warehouse_app/current/app/views/products/show"
>
> The :file option takes an absolute
> file-system path. Of course, you need
> to have rights to the view that you’re
> using to render the content.

Answer (score 0):

It might be more prudent to create a gem that has any shared code (ie. partials) in it so both apps can use it.

Comment: A "gem" is a packaged set of ruby objects that can be easily included in multiple projects.  The Rails equivalent is a plugin, which might be more appropriate here.